# Cant display json data into html using Jquery Ajax post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My html has these lines

```
   <form id="purchaseform">
        <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1">
        <input name="product" type="hidden" value={{item_id}}>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
    </form>
```

After I click submit, I want this to be displayed in this section of my html
        
            your shopping cart:
        
Trying to do this with the ajax method but after clicking submit nothing gets displayed. Can anyone figure out the problem?

```
$("#submit").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault()
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/cart',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#cart-template").html(data)
                    }
                })
               })
```

Comment: Remove your attempt to parse the json.  `dataType: "json",` will make jQuery parse it already

Comment: You should be seeing an error in your console about cannot parse starting at "o" or something.

Comment: I think `$("#submit").submit(function(event){` should be `$("#purchaseform").submit(function(event){`

Comment: Also, even though you shouldn't be using it in this example at all, use `JSON.parse()` rather than `$.parseJSON()` when you need to parse json.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to append an Object/Array to the DOM?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, @AlonEitan I tried with the purchase form but it gives error 500.

Comment: @Taplar how do I display the data then? I removed the dataType: 'json', I think I can get the data sent over but cannot display it in the html.

Comment: That's a good sign, it means that the JS part is working and that you need to debug the code on the server (error 500 is for internal server error)

Comment: That's a broad question.  Your response is going to be an Object with key/value pairs, or it's going to be an Array with stuff in it.  In either case, if you want to add that to your page as html, you have to convert that into the html you desire.  **what** that html needs to look like is entirely up to you.

Comment: thank you for pointing out my mistake, yes it should be purchase form, I had mistakenly used the input id instead of the form id. I will work with this now

Comment: you can use JSON.stringify like this $("#elementId").html(JSON.stringify(data))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one issue with your code, so I will explain why to you in detail.

#### If you are sending trough POST, send the data.

The first issue I saw was that you ain't sending nothing with the AJAX request. To send specific data, use the data property:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/cart',
            data: $(this).serialize(), // Call the form values as a string
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#cart-template").html(data)
            }
        })
```

But, what is `this`?

#### Handle form submit from the form itself.

This means that don't wait until the submit button is pressed. To give your JavaScript code a better context of your app, handle the form submit to start working:

```
$("#purchaseform").submit(function(event){
   ...
})
```

So, `#purchaseform` should be your form tag.

> Handling the form like this, will let you use `this` to reference the actual form that was submitted.

That's why we used: `$(this).serialize()`.

#### Decide what type of data structure you will use.

As I saw in your code, you are supposedly sending `dataTyoe: "json"`, but later on you are using the output of your AJAX request and appending it as HTML.

So, the simplest way if you want to return HTML from the AJAX request, remove the `dataType` property, so your code would look like this:

```
$("#purchaseform").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/cart',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#cart-template").html(data)
            }
        })
})
```

Here is a [LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/gkudpsz5/) so you can try different things around it.